# Vue-router callback when navigation is cancelled

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hook, vue-router

My Vue app shows a loading screen whenever a route is loading because code-split routes sometimes take a few seconds to load. It does this using a global `beforeEach` hook.

```
// App component
this.$router.beforeEach(() => { this.loading = true })
this.$router.afterEach(() => { this.loading = false })
this.$router.onError(() => { this.loading = false })
```

The problem with this is if I create a guard on a route definition (like `beforeEnter`), calling `next(false)` won't trigger `afterEach` or `onError`, so it leaves the app in a loading state forever.

One thing I tried was to use `beforeResolve` instead of `beforeEach`. This didn't work out because my `beforeEnter` route guards are asynchronous, and I want to show the loading screen while they execute.

Another possible solution is to always call `next(error)` instead of `next(false)` so that the `onError` hook is triggered. But that's a bug waiting to happen later on, when someone tries to use the navigation guard API as intended.

One last option is to isolate the `this.loading` logic into a globally-accessible class or event bus and make route guards handle it on a case-by-case basis.

But my preference would be to set it and forget it. Is there a global hook that gets called when navigation is cancelled? And why isn't `afterEach` called in this scenario?

Comment: Here's a link to a relevant github feature request https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2012

Comment: It sounds like this is a bug. However, as an alternative what you can do is create your own AbortError, and throw that, a la your second option. You can add more than one onError handler and just check for your custom error object.